# The texure of the rendered model looks different than in the viewport

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

In my model, I I textured everything and it looks great

[image]

But when I render it, it looks like this

[image]

(I cleared all the other materials to see if that would fix)

The roof texture looks really weird now and I would like to know if there was some way to make the texture version show instead of the material version?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more information. What render engine are you using? Please add images of how you set your material and what kind of coordinates you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you will have to set up materials in order to see UV images in the render, because for the rendering engine more parameters than the image and its mapping are needed. Create basic materials, assign the textures to them and use the UV map in the texture panel. This way it should be close to what you see in the texture view.